# How to view the disk bandwidth used by each process on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

`top` than `m` (view disk iops) than `o` than `write` (order by write desc)

Will show a sort of `iotop` ordering by the process that uses the most write operation per second. Any way to se the bandwidth used with the process instead of the IOPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a shame `iotop` from Linux doesn't exist for FreeBSD, because it provides the output you're looking for. Perhaps [DTrace for FreeBSD](http://wiki.freebsd.org/DTrace) could help you gain some insight into what your processes are doing at the I/O level.